# How to display omdb function returned value in webpage

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications

Can we store the value returned from omdb function `searchOneMovie(moviename)` so that it can be displayed as output in JSP page when button is clicked? I am developing a Web-Application where on clicking the button I should get the details of movie as searched by user but by using `searchOneMovie()` I am getting the output in console not in web page. Please tell how to display `searchOneMovie()` value in JSP page.

CODE:

```
public void search(HttpServletResponse response, String moviename) throws OmdbSyntaxErrorException, OmdbConnectionErrorException, OmdbMovieNotFoundException, IOException {
    Omdb o = new Omdb();
    try {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print(o.searchOneMovie(moviename));
    } catch (Exception ignore) {
    }
}
```

OUTPUT: This output is coming on console but i wan't it in webpage please help.

```
 Mar 13, 2017 8:13:51 PM com.omdbapi.RestClient execute
 INFO: executing GET http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=star+wars HTTP/1.1
 Mar 13, 2017 8:13:52 PM com.omdbapi.Omdb resultToJson
 INFO: received {"Title":"Star Wars: Episode IV - A New     Hope","Year":"1977","Rated":"PG","Released":"25 May 1977","Runtime":"121 min","Genre":"Action, Adventure, Fantasy","Director":"George Lucas","Writer":"George Lucas","Actors":"Mark Hamill, Harrison Ford, Carrie Fisher, Peter Cushing","Plot":"Luke Skywalker joins forces with a Jedi Knight, a cocky pilot, a wookiee and two droids to save the galaxy from the Empire's world-destroying battle-station, while also attempting to rescue Princess Leia from the evil Darth Vader.","Language":"English","Country":"USA","Awards":"Won 6 Oscars. Another 50 wins & 28 nominations.","Poster":"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYzQ2OTk4N2QtOGQwNy00MmI3LWEwNmEtOTk0OTY3NDk2MGJkL2ltYWdlL2ltYWdlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNjc1NTYyMjg@._V1_SX300.jpg","Metascore":"92","imdbRating":"8.7","imdbVotes":"963,318","imdbID":"tt0076759","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}
```

Comment: Consider making a minimal viable example like explained here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve